# B2B vs B2C services - are differences purely relates to business process and flow OR are there differences also in technical architecture?

Tags: design, architecture, api-design

I have some B2B services already exposed to customers who manufacture products and ships to end consumer.

These B2B services are implemented using asp.net web API and is performant enough to handle millions request per day.

Now I need to expose services to end consumer for there product activation and hence it is B2C in nature.

I would like to understand and mainly interested in knowing if there are any important considerations from technical architecture perspective when it comes to implementing B2B vs B2C services ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no fundamental technical differences between B2B and B2C services. Instead, those monikers describe your *sales* strategy and marketing. Quite frequently, the same service is marketed towards both consumers and businesses, but perhaps using different features as selling points.<sup>[1]</sup>

These different features are where there might be some technical differences. E.g. a business client may demand a SLA, so your technical decisions must be able to support the agreed service level. Such agreements are atypical for B2C services. In webapps, a common differentiator is to implement team functionality or external integrations in the business version. This adds complexity to your code base, but doesn't lead to a fundamentally different architecture.

I wouldn't characterize a service as B2C if it merely interacts with consumers (the customers of your customers) without trying to market to them.

<sup>[1]: The B2B/B2C categories start to meld once you consider prosumers and freelancers.</sup>